# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`. in Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have gone over all the answers out there on this error for about a week now.  I still can't seem to get rid of this error.  Any help would be super duper helpful and appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactRouter, {
    Router,
    Route,
    IndexRoute,
    IndexLink,
    Link,
    hashHistory
} from "react-router";

import Home from "./home";
import Lists from "./lists";
import Mailings from "./mailings";
import App from "./app";
import Templates from "./templates";
import subCategorypage from "./subcategoryrepeat";
import Members from "./members";
import Assets from "./assets";
import ImportList from "./importlist";
import MailingWizard from "./mailingwizardone";
import DealerProfile from "./dealerprofile";
import UserProfile from "./userprofile";
import ApiKey from "./apikey";
import Login from "./login";
import NewMember from "./newMemberSlide"
import ImportTemplate from "./importTemplate";
import ImportAsset from "./importAsset";
import Register from "./register";
import FileMap from "./filemap";
import Invite from "./invite";
import MaterialUIAutocomplete from "./searchpiece";
import Example from "./autosuggest";
import NewForm from "./newmemberform";
import SignInForm from "./registrationform";


    var destination = document.querySelector("#container");

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router history={hashHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                <Route path="lists" component={Lists}/>
                <Route path="mailings" component={Mailings}/>
                <Route path="templates" component={Templates} />
                <Route path="subcategoryrepeat/:subcategoryId" component={subCategorypage}/>
                <Route path="members" component={Members}/>
                <Route path="assets" component={Assets}/>
                <Route path="importlist" component={ImportList}/>
                <Route path="mailingwizardone" component={MailingWizard}/>
                <Route path="dealerprofile" component={DealerProfile}/>
                <Route path="userprofile" component={UserProfile}/>
                <Route path="apikey" component={ApiKey}/>
                <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
                <Route path="newMemberSlide" component={NewMember}/>
                <Route path="importTemplate" component={ImportTemplate}/>
                <Route path="importAsset" component={ImportAsset}/>
                <Route path="register" component={Register}/>
                <Route path="filemap" component={FileMap}/>
                <Route path="invite" component={Invite}/>
                <Route path="searchpiece" component={MaterialUIAutocomplete}/>
                <Route path="autosuggest" component={Example}/>
                <Route path="newmemberform" component={NewForm}/>
                <Route path="registrationform" component={SignInForm}/>



            </Route>
        </Router>,
        destination
    );
```

It looks like the code is all correct according to everything I see but the error is still happening.  I have tried it on two operating systems and two browsers.

Comment: which version of router you are using ?

Comment: I am using react router version 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This error just happened to me today, and I saw this question had no further ideas since it was posted last year, so maybe this will help someone else. I wondered if the poster had the same issue I did because they have a long list of Routes and imports, and perhaps some were still unfinished in some way.

If you haven't yet developed that long list of imported components, and some of the imported files are still blank or missing essential parts of React code, I found that it can result in different "invalid prop" errors ('component', 'render', etc.)

If that is the problem, commenting out the lines that refer to files that are not quite developed yet, until they are ready, fixes the error. That is, it enables you to still load your file in the browser while you want to work on it, rather than having it stall on error for incomplete files you want to import.

For example, if the "dealerprofile" component is a blank file still or only partially written, if you comment out the import line for dealerprofile and the  line for dealerprofile, that might fix the error, then you can simply uncomment those lines again once those files are more fully developed themselves.